# Shorthand to write repetitive test in mathematica

Tags: list-manipulation, keyboard

I have the following set of Mathematica statements:

```
xsPoint[top] == rayPoint + d[top]*rayDirection;
xsPoint[bottom] == rayPoint + d[bottom]*rayDirection;
xsPoint[left] == rayPoint + d[left]*rayDirection;
xsPoint[right] == rayPoint + d[right]*rayDirection;
xsPoint[front] == rayPoint + d[front]*rayDirection;
xsPoint[back] == rayPoint + d[back]*rayDirection;
```

Is there a shorthand way to write this so that I only have to write the equation once?  Maybe something with list comprehension?

Comment: `==` is equivalence. It will evaluate to either true or false, but it won't do anything. What are you trying to achieve? Your code, as it stands, is the same as `CompoundExpression @@ Table[xsPoint[i] == rayPoint + d[i]*rayDirection, {i, {top, bottom, left, right, front,back}}]`

Comment: `Table` is the simplest if you're a beginner.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 3):

A combination of [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html), [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html), and [`Slot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html) will do it concisely:

```
xsPoint[#] == rayPoint + d[#]*rayDirection & /@ {top, bottom, left, right, front, back}
```

> ```
> {xsPoint[top] == rayPoint + rayDirection d[top], 
>  xsPoint[bottom] == rayPoint + rayDirection d[bottom], 
>  xsPoint[left] == rayPoint + rayDirection d[left], 
>  xsPoint[right] == rayPoint + rayDirection d[right], 
>  xsPoint[front] == rayPoint + rayDirection d[front], 
>  xsPoint[back] == rayPoint + rayDirection d[back]}
> ```

Comment: @MrWizard You beat me too it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to define a function for `xsPoint` and not and inequality. Lookup [`Equal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html), [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html), and [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) in the documentation.

That being said, you can define a function for `xsPoint` with `SetDelayed` (`:=`) that takes your location parameter. Then use the shorthand notation for a pure function (`#` and `&`) along with `Map` (`/@`) to get the list of equations (or results if the variables have values).

```
xsPoint[location_] := rayPoint + d[location]*rayDirection
xsPoint[#] & /@ {top, bottom, left, right, front, back}
(*
{rayPoint + rayDirection d[top], rayPoint + rayDirection d[bottom], 
 rayPoint + rayDirection d[left], rayPoint + rayDirection d[right], 
 rayPoint + rayDirection d[front], rayPoint + rayDirection d[back]}
*)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No need for the complication of `Function` this way; `xsPoint /@ {. . .}` will yield the same output!  Or did you mean to include the `Equal` part in your Function and forgot?

Comment: Ah, I just realised what you did above. That is an interesting usage.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just make a shorthand for the test? e.g.:

```
xsTest[dir_] := xsPoint[dir] == rayPoint + d[dir]*rayDirection
```

then just use as needed, e.g,:

```
xsTest[top]
```

If new "directions" come about, nothing changes (so no need to add the new "directions" to a map, say).

Comment: A `DownValues` definition is a good alternative to an anonymous function but I fail to understand your second point; either method can be used the same way, right?

Comment: With the not crystal clarity of OP needs, that latter may or may not come into play. Interpreted as xsPoint and d being some functions that are part of a test that is repeated with differing "directions", were new "directions" to come into play, one would have to go through any code using the map and add those new "directions". Of course, the family of "directions" could be some single definition, so perhaps moot. Again, just based on my interpretation of OP in current state, could be utter nonsense...